# File bat search date in csv file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

OK thanks for all information , I change my CVS in :

```
NUMBER;CITY;SERVER;NUMBER1;NUMBER2;EMAIL;ADDRESS
3;3 - NEW YORK;192.168.1.10;32049586848;032059684749;pippo@vision.de;Mießtaler Straße 12 A-9020 Klagenfurt 
4;4 - Rome;192.168.1.22;345689768;0234567890;pluto@vision.uk;Via Platani 00133 22 Rome
```

and I changed the code like this :

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=test.csv

:HOME
cls
set column=""
echo        TEST
echo     1  Search IP
echo     X  Close
echo.

Choice /C 1X /N /M "Please make a selection: "
echo.

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :IP

:IP
set column=SERVER
echo ---- Enter IP ----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:FINDIT
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
   set inline=%%A
   for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%1 in ("!SERVER!") do (
      set "NUMBER=%%~1" & set "CITY=%%~2" & set "SERVER=%%~3" & set "ADDRESS=%%~7"
      if /I "!%column%!" equ "%strsearch%" GOTO :SHOW
   )
)

:NFOUND
echo NOT FOUND Try AGAIN
pause
GOTO :HOME

:SHOW
echo SERVER: %SERVER%
echo Number: %NUMBER%
echo City: %CITY%
echo Address: %ADDRESS%
pause
GOTO :Home

:EXIT
```

Should it work now? What do you think about it ?
I can use csv files and bat files, i cannot use power shell on this system.

I have a file CSV :

```
NCITY;SERVER;NUMBER1;NUMBER2;EMAIL;ADDRESS
3 - NEW YORK;192.168.1.10;32049586848;032059684749;pippo@vision.de;Mießtaler Straße 12 A-9020 Klagenfurt 
4 - Rome;192.168.1.22;345689768;0234567890;pluto@vision.uk;Via Platani 00133 22 Rome
```

I would like to create a bat file that, given an IP, shows me the corresponding number, name and address on the screen.
I was thinking of using this as a base script:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=test.csv

:HOME
cls
set column=""
echo        TEST
echo     1  Search IP
echo     X  Close
echo.

Choice /C 1X /N /M "Please make a selection: "
echo.

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :IP

:IP
set column=SERVER
echo ---- Enter IP ----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:FINDIT
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
   set inline=%%A
   for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%1 in ("!SERVER!") do (
      set "SERVER=%%~1" & set "fname=%%~2" & set "comp=%%3" & set "cit=%%4" & set "stat=%%5"
      if /I "!%column%!" equ "%strsearch%" GOTO :SHOW
   )
)

:NFOUND
echo NOT FOUND Try AGAIN
pause
GOTO :HOME

:SHOW
echo SERVER: %SERVER%
echo Number: %lname%,%fname%
echo City: %cit%
echo Address: %stat%
pause
GOTO :Home

:EXIT
```

Can you help me fix it?
I haven't used bat files for a long time
thanks

Comment: why do you use `delims=,` when your `csv` is delimited with `;`` ?

Comment: `set "SERVER=%%~1"` - shouldn't it be `%%~2`? (same with the rest of the variables in that line)

Comment: What does this have to do with searching for dates?  There is no dates in your data.

Comment: Looks like you tried to obfuscate your data and code and did not correctly match everything together.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, you can't use PowerShell. Perhaps you should wonder why? Please do not consider this an answer for your question. However, someone else might benefit from it.

Using PowerShell for interactive console apps is a bit of underkill for PowerShell's capabilities. But, it can do it. And, it is already on your supported Windows system; nothing additional to install.

Save this in a file named Find-FromServerCsv.ps1

Run it in a PowerShell console using `.\Find-FromServerCsv`

Run it in a cmd.exe console using `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Find-FromServerCSV.ps1"`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
$CsvFile = '.\csvpick.txt'
$Title = "Welcome"
$Info = "Just to Demo Promt for Choice"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @('&Search by IP', '&Exit')
[int]$defaultchoice = 1

$opt = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title , $Info , $Options,$defaultchoice)
switch($opt) {
    0 {
        Write-Verbose 'doing search by IP'
        $IpAddress = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the IP address: '
        Import-Csv -Path $CsvFile -Delimiter ';' |
            Where-Object { $_.SERVER -eq $IpAddress } |
            Select-Object -Property NUMBER1,NCITY,ADDRESS
    }
    1 {
        Write-Verbose 'doing exit'
    }
}
```